# Laravel Auditing Duplicate Auditing Entries

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-auditing

I followed the instructions from [the laravel auditing docs](https://laravel-auditing.com/guide/installation.html) to install it in my project.

Afterwards I edited my laravel model:

```php
class MyModel extends Model implements Auditable
{
    use CamelCaseAttributes;
    use AuditingAuditable;
...
```

Now I see the entries in the `audits` table but it seems that for every action (created/updated/etc.) there are 2 identical entries. I checked the query output using `DB::enableQueryLog and DB::getQueryLog` which shows 1 Update query and 2 inserts into the audits table with the same values.

Any ideas how to avoid the duplicate entries?

```
php => 8.0
laravel => 8.0
laravel-audits => 13.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright after debugging the issue for quite some time I noticed that the Auditing event was fired twice for every send.

The issue was the booted method in the model:

```php
class MyModel extends Model implements Auditable
{
    use CamelCaseAttributes;
    use AuditingAuditable;

    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new CustomScope());

        parent::booted(); // this line is the issue
    }
...
```

The `Auditable` trait was initialized twice since the laravel Model which is my base class recursivly initializes the traits on the class in its `booted()` method. This causes 2 `auditing` events and therefor 2 db entries.

Fix was to remove the `parent::booted();` line completly since the constructor of the laravel Model::class is enough to set everything up.